# jquery auto complete plugin,json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My requirement is to implement auto complete in my text box with my rails application
I have downloaded the jquery auto complete plugin.Please help me with how to implement it .

My controller code:

```
 def new
@release = Release.new
@ic_ids = params[:ic_ids] ? params[:ic_ids] : []
**@testers = User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester')) order by name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>30)**   
 if params[:project_id]
  @release.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
end
end
```

I want to create auto complete for **@testers.**

My view code:

```
 %td.grid.full_panels
    -table_panel "Assign Testers" do
      %table
        %th Name
        -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
        = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        **= form.text_field :tester_tokens**
```

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Did you try implementing it..!

Comment: Yes Sudhir i tried with the following change in my view file :  :javascript
  data = #{@testers.to_json} 
= javascript_include_tag :defaults, :cache => true
 and in my application.js  $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#root_name').autocomplete(data);
 });
But I am not seeing the data being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement auto-complete, there's really 2 ways to approach it.

1. Bring all the data in advance.
2. Send ajax request to the server on each "keydown/keyup" or "onchange"

For the first method, there's a really cool jquery plugin called [jsonSuggest](http://tomcoote.co.uk/javascript/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box-v2/)
and it's really easy to implement. 
You need a json object in (id,text) pairs like so :

`var myData = [{ id :  "someId" , text : "someText"} , ... ]`

and then you invoke the following code :

`$("#myInput").jsonSuggest({ data : myData , onSelect: function(item){ /* callback code */} })`

This can fit even for thousands of objects. It will give a better performance that multiple ajax calls to the server.
If you rather use the jquery-ui plugin, have a look at [the default example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default)

The other method (multiple ajax requests) is quite similar, but I don't think that jsonsuggest supports it. It is supported by the jquery-ui plugin. 
For this case, you should have a look at [the remote example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)